# Batch file (.bat) equivalent to a POSIX-like shell script (.sh)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sh, glob

I have this line in a `.sh` file : `easy_install -Z --prefix=$PREFIX *.egg`

Now I am working on Windows and have translated this command to what I think is the equivalent batch-file command:

```
easy_install -Z --prefix=%PREFIX% *.egg
```

However, I get the following following error (with `%PREFIX%` containing `c:\path\to\site-packages`):

```
Creating C:\path\to\site-packages\site.py
error: Not a URL, existing file, or requirement spec: '*.egg'
```

Comment: I know little of cmd, so I am not sure, but a big difference I think is that wildcards are expanded by the shell, while cmd does not do that expansion. This means that in shell easy_install receives a list of files corresponding to "*.egg", while under windows this does not happens normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[linxufan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7332147/linuxfan) provided the crucial pointer:

**In Windows batch files, the shell (`cmd.exe`) does *not* automatically perform *globbing*** (expansion of filename patterns (wildcard expressions) to a list of matching filenames).
Commands that do support globbing on Windows, such as `dir`, implement it *themselves*.

Instead, *literal* string `*.egg` is passed to your target program, which is clearly not the intent here.

Therefore, you must **do your own globbing, and pass the result to the target program.**

Doing so *robustly* in a batch file is tricky, however; the following works under the assumption that your filenames have neither *embedded* `"` nor `!` chars:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Do your own globbing and collect the filenames in variable %files%.
set "files="
for %%f in (*.egg) do set files=!files! "%%f"

easy_install -Z --prefix=%PREFIX% %files%
```

- `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is needed so you can build up the `%files%` variable iteratively in a `for` loop (`!...!`-enclosed variable references are then *dynamically* expanded) - the downside is that `!` chars. in the *value* of the variable are also interpreted.
- To also handle filenames with embedded *spaces* correctly, each filename is added with enclosing `"` chars. - the downside is that filenames with embedded `"` chars. wouldn't be handled correctly, but that's rare.

Note that if there's ever a chance that `%PREFIX%` contains spaces or other shell metacharacters, pass the option double-quoted: `"--prefix=%PREFIX%"`.